# Implementing line with layout android xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a xml layout something like this
[image]

I used this to draw a separator line but don't know how to implement a layout or textView inbetween.Is there any way I can do this?

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#000000" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="textview"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like would work:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use weight properly in sync with your code.

```
                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0.6dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/black" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <TextView
     android:id="@+id/my_text"
     android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

     <View
     android:id="@+id/my_line"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="1dp"
     android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/my_text"/>

     <View
     android:id="@+id/my_line2"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="1dp"
     android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/my_text"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```